# dataframe sort by max value and show row names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this

```
Name    Shop   Sales
a        First  10
c        Second 5
b        First 8
d        Second 4
e        Third 30
g        First 11
```

And I want to get values from 'Name' column that have highest values in 'Sales' column, grouped by 'Shop' and sorted so that highest value 'Sales'.
So practically I want to return this:

```
Third  e  30
First  g  11
Second  c  5
```

I managed to do this:

```
grouped=df.groupby(['Shop'], sort=False)['Sales'].max()
grouped.sort_index(ascending=False)
```

which yields:

```
Third   30
First   11
Second   5
```

But I am not sure how to access coresponding names for it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices of `max` values of `Sales`, then select by `loc` and last [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
print (df.groupby('Shop')['Sales'].idxmax())

Shop
First     5
Second    1
Third     4
Name: Sales, dtype: int64

print (df.loc[df.groupby('Shop')['Sales'].idxmax()].sort_values('Sales', ascending=False))
  Name    Shop  Sales
4    e   Third     30
5    g   First     11
1    c  Second      5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nlargest` method:

```
In [115]: df.groupby('Shop', as_index=False) \
            .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, columns='Sales')) \
            .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
Out[115]:
  Name    Shop  Sales
5    g   First     11
1    c  Second      5
4    e   Third     30
```

Or if you don't need original index values - here is a better approach from @jezrael:

```
In [122]: df.set_index('Name').groupby('Shop')['Sales'].nlargest(1).reset_index()
Out[122]:
     Shop Name  Sales
0   First    g     11
1  Second    c      5
2   Third    e     30
```